# What are 'manual' storageclasses and kubernetes.io/no-provisioner provisioner in kubernetes. Are they kubernetes provided defaults

Tags: kubernetes, local-storage, storage-class-specifier

I could not get documentation on `manual` storageclasses and `kubernetes.io/no-provisioner` provisioner type. Could some one please explain them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manual storage classes are nothing but a Kubernetes storage mechanism that lets you dynamically provision persistent volumes (PV) in a Kubernetes cluster. Kubernetes administrators define classes of storage, and then pods can dynamically request the specific type of storage.

Whereas "Provisioner" is used especially when dynamic provisioning is involved. [kubernetes.io/no-provisioner](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/#local) is one of the plugins from the storage plugins. This is a storage class that can be used as default when local persistent volumes are manually provisioned. This also indicates that no dynamic provisioning should occur for a specific StorageClass. Essentially, it means that the user is responsible for manually creating PersistentVolumes for any claims that use this StorageClass.

Refer to this [Kubernetes StorageClass: Concepts and Common Operations](https://bluexp.netapp.com/blog/cvo-blg-kubernetes-storageclass-concepts-and-common-operations) authored by Yifat Perry and official documentation on [storage class](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/).

Answer (score 4):

> ...could not get documentation on manual storageclasses

An arbitrary name as it does not require CSI driver to provision volume. It's a name that you can used in PV/PVC without actually create a StorageClass for it. Checkout the official example [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-persistent-volume-storage/).

If you are interested in how a StorageClass like this might look like:

```
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: manual
provisioner: kubernetes.io/no-provisioner
```